# Qt: Should i run QFileWatcher on a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qthread

I have a program which relies on the files that are added to a folder. No file can be unregistred, even if the user adds MANY (>200) files to this folder.

When a signal from QFileWatcher is received I'm reading and creating an image out of some of the data, and the execution of this can take up to a few seconds. Both the QFileWatcher and the function that handles the signals resides in the same class. I'm worried that the class might be busy at times and potentially cause QFileWatcher not to register some files.

Should I add QFileWatcher to a thread to ensure the registration of data?

**What I'm doing as of now**

In main.cpp:

```
...
MainWindow w;
w.setupFolderMonitoring();
...
```

In mainwindow.h:

```
...
public:
  void setupFolderMonitoring();
  void detectFolderChanges();
private:
  QString monitoredPath;
  QFileSystemWatcher watcher;
...
```

In mainwindow.cpp:

```
...
void MainWindow::setupFolderMonitoring() {
    watcher.addPath(monitoredPath);
    QObject::connect(&watcher, SIGNAL(directoryChanged(QString)), this, 
    SLOT(detectFolderChanges()));
}
void MainWindow::detectFolderChanges() {
    qDebug() << "Dir was changed";
}
...
```

Comment: The file watching functionality is provided by the operating system kernel and possibly system-wide file monitoring services. All of this works asynchronously and your application won't lose any events simply by being busy - the API is designed to deal with that. You should worry about providing smooth UI feel to your user, though. In Qt, there is no notion of a "lost" signal. Directly connected signals are simply indirect function calls, and queued slot calls are put in the event loop. Nothing will be "lost".

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. It can be difficult to wrap your head around some of these subjects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if your data processing can take longer than a second, you should probably not be doing it on the main thread in order to avoid non-responsive GUI.

Furthermore, when working on folder monitoring in Windows, I observed that the Windows file-monitoring mechanism will start dropping events if the monitoring thread is busy processing data. So that's another good reason to move data processing to it's own thread.

The approach I've taken before was to create a data processing `QObject`, "move" it to a new thread (using `QObject::moveToThread(...)`) and connecting it to the filesystem monitor and the GUI using signals and slots.

To be entirely honest, I did not use Qt's filesystem monitoring because I needed more info than Qt provides for file rename events. So I had to use the Windows filesystem monitoring API directly. But I don't think Qt can work around limitations in the OS in terms of processing large-scale changes.

Comment: I would argue that doing anything in the GUI thread that blocks for more than 50ms on an i5 machine is unacceptable. On most desktop hardware these days, a full screen blit takes less than 50ms, so you can do all of rendering in another thread even when you use a widgets API. With C++11 and Qt 5, it's rather easy to write heavily multithreaded code without even using `QObject` facilities. `QtConcurrent::run` to the rescue :)

Comment: Thank you for answering one more of my questions deGoot :) So if i have the data processing on a another thread, and the filesystem monitor on the main thread i should be ok? If i add a dir iterator in detectFolderChanges(), simulate a data processing with a QTimer and add 200 files, the program crashes - this is the scenario i would like the program to be able to handle.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've handled more than 200 files previously. It's been a while since I ran those tests. You may not want to create a new thread for each change, through (might have some performance penalty there). I created a queue to track changes and my `detectFolderChanges` would enqueue the changes and notify the data processor that more changes are available to be processed. The data processor would then dequeue the file change information, process it for as long as needed and notify the GUI that processing is complete.

Comment: I had something similar in mind, but i havent really used threads before, so i'm a little unsure how it's gonna work. How does this sound: I have essentially two threads; main thread and a data processing thread. I have a class on the main thread with a file queue, a bool `shouldUpdate`, a `QFileWatcher` and a signal function. When changes are detected, i set `shouldUpdate` true, add the filenames to the queue and signal the data processing thread to start processing the files in the queue.

Comment: This seems to work, but i do have to iterate through the whole folder 200 times, clearing it each time and then adding the new files. Maybe a delay of some kind would be good.